# Trying to minimize checks of atomics on every iteration, V2

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have an app which has 2 threads: the main thread, and a worker thread.

The main thread has a `MainUpdate()` function that gets called in a continuous loop. As part of its job, that `MainUpdate()` function might call a `ToggleActive()` method on some worker objects, which might or might not be currently running on the worker thread. That `ToggleActive()` method is used to turn the worker objects on/off.

The flow is something like this.
More description follows after the code.

```
// MainThread
ThreadPool threadPool;
std::atomic_bool threadRunning = false;
std::vector<WorkerObject*> workerObjects;

// Main loop
while(true) {
    MaybeRunThread();
    MainUpdate(...);
}

void MaybeRunThread() {
  if (threadRunning) 
    return;
  threadRunning = true;

  // Run the set of worker objects in different thread.
  // When all active objects have ran, lambda is removed from pool.
  threadPool.Enqueue([]{
    for (auto& w: workerObjects) {
      if(w.IsActive())
        w.Work();
    }
    threadRunning = false;
  });
}

void MainUpdate(...) {
    for(auto& obj: workerObjects) {
        if (SomeReason()) 
          obj.ToggleActive(GetSomeBool());
    }
    // ... other code
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------
// Worker object base class. 
// Update() & IsActive() run on different thread.
struct WorkerObject {
    virtual Update(...) = 0;

    void ToggleActive(bool active) {
        mIsActive = active;      
    }

    bool IsActive() const {
         return mIsActive
    }

private:
    bool mIsActive = true;
};
```

I'm trying to avoid making `mIsActive` a `std::atomic_bool` because there are many worker objects running at any one time, and thus there would be many atomic bool checks every iteration.

I understand that there is a race condition when `MainUpdate()` calls `obj.ToggleActive()` and the worker thread checks `if (w.IsActive())` in `MaybeRunThread()`. For the current execution of the main loop, the bool update might not be visible. But, that's ok with me.

What I'd like to know is if the bool update will be visible to the worker thread on the **next** invocation of `MaybeRunThread()`. When the lambda exits, it is removed from the thread-pool, and it would be enqueued into the thread pool afterwards, in a subsequent call to `MaybeRunThread()`. I'm thinking that the value of `WorkerObject.mIsActive` would be the refreshed on the CPU prior to the next thread run, and thus the `if` check would yield the correct value that was previously set in `MainUpdate()`.

Is my assessment correct?

Comment: The thing with _data races_ is not just reading/writing wrong data, but also that compiler/processor does a lot of optimization based on assumption there is no data racing. I can't say your code will work as you expected or not. But even if it does now, it will be hard to ensure that in the future when there are changes in your code/compiler/hardware,...

Comment: "I'm trying to avoid making mIsActive a std::atomic_bool", — you want to have thread-safety without paying for it. It does not work that way. There are ways to "cheat" hardware, but all of them either rely on advanced knowledge of your code (that can not be possibly be conferred within a single question) or need OS/hardware-dependent hacks: RCU, guard pages, memory keys, taking advantage of quirks of specific CPU family… Hint: read of `atomic_bool` on Intel should cost close to nothing, — [it is compiled to single `mov` instruction](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/cpp/cpp0xmappings.html).

Comment: Post a [MCVE] that will compile and run.

Comment: What is a "worker thread"? The opposite of a "shirker thread"?

Comment: @user1643723 - I'm not trying to "cheat" anything. I described a problem, and I solution that I think could work, but which I'm not sure off. Namely, I'm trying to minimize atomic queries.

Comment: @Dess it is impossible to further reduce "atomic queries" in the currently posted code, because atomic fetches are just normal fetches on x86. You can completely replace `atomic_bool` with normal boolean variables and it will still compile and "work" on modern x86 processors. However doing so may break your code in compiler-dependent way.

Comment: Just use the correct `atomic_bool`.